# HTTP Header 404 on a viewable page

Tags: apache, http, http-headers

I would appreciate a minute of someones time just to help me with a server issue.

I have a site that serves up .php pages, when I say served up there is a wordpress php inculde tag at the top of every page that includes the blog snippets.

These pages are served as .php and they render fine in the browser. However when you do a crawl test on them they show a 404?

I run an Apache server, which I hope I have set up properly.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Haydyn

Answer (score 0):

How are you crawling the pages, please specify the commands.

If you are using wget, do a wget -S http://sitename, to get the server headers. It may help in debugging.

Do you have http_proxy environment variable setup ?